# Sql Server 2005 how to change dbo login name

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, security, active-directory

I have a database with user 'dbo' that has a login name "domain\xzy".  How do I change it from "domain\xzy" to "domain\abc".

Answer (score 105, accepted):

I figured it out. Within SQL Management Studio you have to right-click on the database -> Properties -> Files -> Owner field. Change this field to the login name/account that you want associated with the "dbo" username for that database. Please keep in mind that the login name/account you choose must already be setup in the sql server under Security -> Logins

Comment: Or make the same change via code:  use someDB;go;exec sp_changedbowner 'newOwner'

Answer (score 5):

If you are trying to remap a login to a db user you can use sp_change_user_login

exec sp_change_user_login 'Update_One', 'user', 'login'

Comment: The sproc appears to be 'sp_change_users_login' (i.e. _users_). FYI the BOL also states that it's deprecated and ALTER USER should be used instead in the future.

Comment: Although usually this would work, the stored proc quite specifically **rejects** an attempt to alter the **dbo** user in this manner.

Answer (score 1):

PhantomTypist gives a good answer using the GUI.  For achieving the same result with TSQL, you can use this code:

```
USE [My_Database_Name]
GO
EXEC dbo.sp_changedbowner @loginame = N'domain\abc', @map = false
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a Windows login, not a SQL Server login, so you cannot 'change' the login name since it is linked to the user account in Active Directory.

Create a new Server Login (Windows) mapped to the new windows user (and remove the old one if necessary). Then in login's Security > User Mapping, permission that login to the appropriate database as user 'dbo' (or assign to the db_owner role)

Comment: I suspect you're not properly understanding the SQL Server security model. The *whole server instance* has **logins** associated with the server. These may be SQL or Windows logins. Each database on the server has a number of **users** with permissions to access that database. The database **user** is associated with a SQL **login** which are usually (but not required to be) the same. **dbo** is a *special user* on each database. OP is not trying to and a new arbitrary user with db_owner rights to the database - he's trying to associate a different server login with the standard **dbo** user.